# Cannot delete expired key

Tags: apt, package-management, update-manager

While trying to manually get update I got a gpg error:

```
W: GPG error: http://apt.freegeek.org precise Release: The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1422819173
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://apt.freegeek.org/ubuntu/ precise/main i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/apt.freegeek.org_ubuntu_dists_precise_main_binary-i386_Packages)
```

When I try to delete key with  `sudo apt-key del`  I get this:

```
gpg: key "1422819173" not found: eof
gpg: 1422819173: delete key failed: eof
```

This is keeping the update manager from doing its thing. Any help is appreciated.
-k.

Answer (score 0):

I've added `deb http://apt.freegeek.org/ubuntu precise main` into my `/etc/apt/sources.list`

And got the error

```
W: GPG error: http://apt.freegeek.org precise InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 0261FE3D0875A635
```

So I've requested to receive the newest GPG key for freegreek.org:

```
sudo gpg --keyserver pgpkeys.mit.edu --recv-key 0261FE3D0875A635
```

and added the key:

```
sudo gpg -a --export-keys 0261FE3D0875A635 | sudo apt-key add -
```

and then launch `sudo apt-update` but got the same error:

```
W: GPG error: http://apt.freegeek.org precise InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1422819173
```

Therefore I've checked the key list:

```
gpg --list-keys
/root/.gnupg/pubring.gpg
------------------------
pub   4096R/0875A635 2009-07-13 [expired: 2015-02-01]
uid                  Freegeek Portland Packages (archive signing only) <ass@freegeek.org>
```

You could realize that even the newest key of freegeek.org repository was already expired in **2015-02-01**.

So sadly, you can't fix this yourself, unless you import the new key, once the freegeek.org repository updates their keys to sign the files.

You can safely ignore these messages if you aren't using packages of these repositories. The message can be removed if you remove or comment out the repository from your `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
#deb http://apt.freegeek.org/ubuntu precise main
```